# redux-storage with redux-saga - not saving

Tags: redux, redux-saga, redux-middleware, redux-storage

I am trying to use both the redux-storage and redux-saga middleware for redux.  Each middleware works great on its own, but when I apply redux-storage with redux-saga, the store does not load the prior state.  I am adding the middleware as follows:

```
const combinedReducers = storage.reducer(combineReducers(reducers));
import createEngine from 'redux-storage-engine-reactnativeasyncstorage';
const engine = createEngine('storage-key');
const storageMiddleWare = storage.createMiddleware(engine);
const sagaMiddleWare = createSagaMiddleware(mySagas); 
export const store  = createStore(combinedReducers, applyMiddleware( sagaMiddleWare, storageMiddleWare)); 
 const load = storage.createLoader(engine);
 load(store).then(() => 
    {   
        console.log("Loaded State");
        console.log(store.getState());

    }).done();
```

Answer (score 1):

Middlewares execute in the order they're passed into `applyMiddleware`. Loading from storage should be before the saga middleware, eg:

```
const finalCreateStore = compose(
  applyMiddleware(
    storage.createMiddleware(engine),
    createSagaMiddleware(sagas)
  )
)(createStore)
```

Answer (score 0):

D'oh!  A bunch of 'EFFECT_TRIGGERED' Actions are emitted right away from redux-saga. These trigger in redux-storage a save event of an empty store, before the store has loaded.  The solution is to add EFFECT_TRIGGERED to the blacklist when creating the redux-storage middleware like so:

```
const storageMiddleWare = storage.createMiddleware(engine, [= 'EFFECT_TRIGGERED']);
```

Comment: 'EFFECT_TRIGGERED' is triggered only in dev. mode. And if you add a sagaMonitor it'll intercept all the monitoring events and can also print a trace of the saga activity if you type $$LogSagas() on the console (see example here https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga/blob/master/examples/async/src/store/configureStore.js)

Comment: Thank you! - do you have a best practice for using this in conjunction with another middleware, like redux-storage?